# Load content in p:chips

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a p:chips and I'm trying to load content in it to edit later, but when I load it the component get stuck and I cant add o delete content

```
    private List<String> lista_att;
this.lista_att.add("HELLO");


public List<String> getLista_att() {
    return lista_att;
}

public void setLista_att(List<String> lista_att) {
    this.lista_att = lista_att;
}

<p:chips id="chips_att_edit" 
    styleClass="ui-chip-anadir" 
    value="#{Contactos.lista_att}"/>
```

Thank you all

Comment: Any errors? If it gets 'stuck' there is a high chance there is an error on the client or the server

Comment: If you're using Chrome, Firefox or Safari, you could open the network pane from the developer tools and check the server response. If there's any error it should appear there.

Comment: sorry I misspoke, i mean stuck in the way i cant add or delete content preload

Comment: @Kukeltje i dont see any error

Comment: How is your list initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it updating primefaces version to 6.2 
thanks all